# How can I call a function before it is defined?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an AJAX call placed inside a function, which is called through PHP when there is an error (such as an input field is empty) to display a notification to the user, however I am receiving this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: sendnotification is not defined

I know why this is... but I don't know how to fix it. It is because I am calling a function which has not yet been defined. Here is an extremely cut-down version of two of my files:

index.php:

```
<?php

include('con.php'); // the file which connects to the database

echo'<script>sendnotification();</script>'; // calls the function which is in footer.php

include('header.php'); // the file which contains the document headers and imports the jQuery and other libraries

include('footer.php');

?>
```

I cannot place the echo line after I import `header.php` because it is inside a function which validates a form and other `if` statements will cause a 'headers already sent' error.

footer.php:

```
<script>
function sendnotification() {
   // do something
}
</script>
```

Comment: Define it before you use it, or have your `sendnotification()` calls wait for the document to be ready.

Comment: @ceejayoz I had thought about that, but I can't use `$(document).ready` because jQuery has not yet been imported!

Comment: Horrible way to integrate scripts. Consider separating concerns and stop mixing javascript in your php

Answer (score 0):

`echo'<script>sendnotification();</script>';` will immediately call the send notification function. However, since you defined the function in the footer, it will throw an error, since the footer hasn't loaded yet.

To fix this, put the

```
<script>
function sendnotification() {
   // do something
}
</script>
```

Somewhere above the `<script>sendnotification();</script>`

Or, you could check if the document is ready.

```
<script>
function sendnotification() {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            clearInterval(interval);
            // do something
        }
     }, 100);
}
</script>
```

Comment: I need `sendnotification();` function to be in `footer.php` so all files can call it

Comment: You could have the `sendnotifiation` function wait for the document to ready like ceejayoz suggested.

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: @TheCodesee Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

What if you call it after the header (which according to you comments, is where you include jQuery) is included?

```
<?php

include('con.php'); // the file which connects to the database

include('header.php'); // the file which contains the document headers and imports the jQuery and other libraries

echo'<script>$(document).ready(function(){sendnotification();});</script>'; // calls the function which is in footer.php

include('footer.php');

?>
```

Comment: Unfourtunately I can't because the `echo` line is inside a function which validates a form and I will receive the 'headers already sent' error.

Comment: then you'll need to call it in the onload event of the body